# Which charge in the diagram has greater magnitude?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

> Which charge in the diagram has greater magnitude? The positive charge or the negative charge?
>
> [image]

I feel that there are two contradicting factors here.

- The positive charge emanates more field lines.
- The negative charge has a more radial electric field. On the contrary, the positive charge seems to have a more deformed/distorted electric field due to influence of the negative charge.

But which factor contributes more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a gaussian surface of same area around both the charges separately, you will clearly see the answer(electric field passing through a closed surface is $\simeq$charge enclosed by that surface)

Answer (score 0):

The charge which has more field lines is the one of greater magnitude.

Comment: But why not the one which has less distorted field?

Comment: @ZOZ The reason that the field lines are distorted on the left hand charge is that it has more field lines coming out of it than the one on the right side, so they have to be drawn closer together.

Comment: If that is the case why are the field lines less "radial" in nature?If there are more field lines then also the field lines could be more symmetrically placed about the positive charge but that is not the case.Why?